# How to choose an op-amp used as a buffer

Tags: operational-amplifier, component-selection

I am having difficulty choosing an op-amp for essentially a one-off design.  All I am trying to do is buffer inputs to a +/- 10V 16 bit ADC.  Super high precision is not necessary, but I would like to be within 100mV of the actual value.

I have several voltages that I will be monitoring all within the +/- 10V range.  I want an op-amp to buffer these voltages before sending to a 16 bit ADC.  I already have a 12V regulator, so I would like to power it with that.  When searching for these parameters, I still get hundreds of results.  How do I pick an op-amp?  LM741 should be able to do this, but so should a LMP7702.  Which one should I use?  How do you decide?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.  I've put a bunch of catch-all caps on the input to filter.  Not sure if that is the best approach, but that is what I have for now.

[image]

EDIT:

I've decided to go with an AD822 op amp.  It basically came down to what is available to me within the +/- 12V range and that had a readily available model.  Follow-up question:

The datasheet for the AD822 shows a unity gain circuit that has no input resistors and no feedback resistors.  I was under the impression that you had to balance the inputs.  Also that you may need some sort of feedback resistor with a small cap across it to prevent oscillations. Maybe because the bias current is so low for this amp, it doesn't matter?  If I were using a large gain, I could see it becoming an issue.  Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Bandwidth requirements?

Comment: This is another thing I don't know how to determine.  Is that just switching speed?  These are going to be DC input voltages being buffered by the op amp for isolation purposes.

Comment: If I really can't think of any other electronic criterium to select for, I select the one that's available in the packages I want (e.g. DIP & SOIC), that's available at the vendors I like, that has lowest delivery time, that has a reputable manufacturer, that is the cheapest. Usually that leaves only one, or few enough to actually review and compare the datasheets.

Comment: Another thing: Your LM741 and LMP7702 differ significantly. The 7702 is a much more sophisticated (and probably expensive) device. It is Rail-Rail Input/Output (RRIO), which the 741 isn't. Worst case the output swing might even be too little with +/-12V supplies, specs are given only at +/-15V. The 7702's CMOS input stage has much higher input impedance, which might be as low as 300k for the 741. 7702 also has higher GBW but isn't unconditionally stable. Finally the offset voltage/bias current differ by orders of magnitude ("precision").
So overall you /do/ have something to weigh up here...

Comment: You have an RC on the input that is limiting your circuit bandwidth to ~12Hz.  Additionally, your requirement to follow the voltage within 100mV is very lax.  Any opamp anywhere can meet these requirements as a voltage follower.  Also, if you are doing a voltage follower, R84 should be 0&Omega;, or a dead short.

Comment: You're probably aware that you're wasting 5 precious bits or so if you gimp your accuracy to 100 mV. Doesn't matter though because any opamp will be far better than that. :)

Comment: @DerManu That's why I gave those two examples.  Both should be able to do the job, but I don't know why I would need one over the other, specifically in the case of a buffer.  I imagine I am overcomplicating this.  I'm just trying to get to a point where I pick something based on all of the normally specified specs rather than just what's in stock.

Comment: @slightlynybbled I didn't take into account the RC limiter.  I just through those in as a basic filter.  This is for a DC voltage monitor.  If I kept it limited to ~12Hz, how does that translate to the kS/s rate of my ADC (250 kS/s)?  Does it just make my maximum sample rate 12 Hz?  I guess I'm confused because this is monitoring a DC signal.

Comment: @pipe Yes I believe 16 bits over a 10V range gives me about 0.15 mV of resolution.  I'm probably only going to be displaying voltage to the 10s of mV anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be unwise to use a LMP7702, since the absolute maximum supply voltage is 13.2V and you want to slap 24V across it.. instant crack-sizzle-pop, most likely.

Your high power supply voltage is one of the most significant constraints, add things like bias current, offset voltage, supply current, gain-bandwidth and so on. Add 'in-stock' at your favorite distributor, sort by available quantity if that is important to you, package, but even after that you'll probably be left with  hundreds to a couple thousand different choices.

In this case, a few-penny LM324 quad may meet your specifications. The 741 is obsolete. You could use a JFET op-amp like the TL084 (again very cheap), or trade up to a precision op-amp for $2 to $5 each, such as the ADA4075 (at the lower end of that scale in cost and some aspects of performance).

Comment: Thank you for catching that!  I read the sheet as +/- 12V would be ok.  Didn't realize that was a single ended spec.  I suppose I just need to do some more reading in my 'Art of Electronics' book to figure out exactly what kind of bias current, offset voltage, etc I need.  For a buffer, I figured it really didn't matter too much.  Money for these components isn't such an issue since this is essentially a one off.

Comment: I was hoping you might take a look at my edit and give some quick feedback.

Comment: The resistor is to balance voltages due to bias currents. The AD822 is a FET input op-amp and has negligible bias current, so you don't need the resistor nor do you need the capacitor across it. Worst case bias current at room temperature is only 10-20pA and even at 85°C would contribute less than 10uV- utterly negligible for an op-amp with 1-1.5mV Vos.